# Retry logic and connection pooling for Azure sql Db with nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, botframework, azure-node-sdk

I have a bot built using botbuilder Sdk V3 that needs to make azure sql Db calls upon user's questions. We have about 10k users who might be accessing this bot in production making concurrent requests (not all 10k but few ) few times per day.

I am thinking to have some Retry logic in my code, connection pooling, connection timeouts that will help to manage database connections gracefully.

I have tried sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs)
which doesn't do any retry or pooling.

I have searched all [examples](https://github.com/rgl/azure-content/tree/master/articles/sql-database) here but didn't find nodejs example doing what I need.

I am expecting to do something like this mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious) and [tedious connection pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious-connection-pool).  I've used them for Azure SQL in production for over 3 years and it's worked great (without special retry logic).